# using sub function in r to retrieve specific text between hyphens

Tags: r, regex

I have rows containing strings such as

```
bye-hi-hello-seeya
```

Specifically I want to extract "hello", the string before the last hyphen or you can see it as the string between last two hyphens.

looked through at several examples online but can't seem to find specific ones where we are looking at the count of hyphens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to extract the text between last two hyphens.

```
sub(".*-(.*)-.*", "\\1", "bye-hi-hello-seeya")
#[1] "hello"

sub(".*-(.*)-.*", "\\1", "bye-hi-seeya")
#[1] "hi"
```

string before last hyphen can be written as

```
sub(".*?(\\w+)-\\w+$", "\\1", "bye-hi-hello-seeya")
#[1] "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `word` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
word(str1, -2, sep="-")
#[1] "hello"
word(str1, -3, sep="-")
#[1] "hi"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "bye-hi-hello-seeya"
```